# What kind of client-side templating should I use with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, handlebars.js, pug

I am planning to start development with Node.js and I decided to use a stack of MongoDB and Express.js with a topping of Ember.js. When it comes to choosing templating for my views, I found two possible solutions, namely Jade and Handlebars.

My issue is that after a bunch of searches I found that Handlebars is often mentioned as the de facto templating for Ember.js, while Jade is mentioned as the de facto for Node.

I heard people say that if I don't use Handlebars with Ember I'm losing much of the goodness that Ember provides.

On the other hand, I heard the same analogy with Node.js and Jade, and I also kind of like Jade more for its Haml-like syntax.

Which should I choose of the two? Do I really lose functionality if I choose one over the other? I feel like I have to.

Comment: I suggest you try it out first and see if you get what you want

Comment: I have read quite a lot about both Handlebars and Jade, but I'm afraid I don't understand what people meant by "you might lose some of the goodness that Node.js/Ember.js provides by not using Jade/Handlebars".

Comment: The benefit of using a framework like Ember is you are only sending down JSON data to the browser (you have to initially send the template to the browser but the template plus JSON data is less than raw HTML). The JSON data will help reduce the overhead that is seen in normal web development. If you use Jade, you will be sending down chucks of HTML instead.

Comment: This is a constructive question.  Do not mindlessly close as "shopping list."

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer no good.  Better to pick a framework that is robust under requirement expansion - even if it's hard to get to work right the first try.

Comment: @djechlin This isn't a constructive question. It is asking for or opinion and the question already says that some people think other than some other people. That means it has a high risk of getting a debat it that means it doesn't fit a Q/A site.

Comment: @WouterJ incorrect, the OP is explicit that the two common viewpoints apply to different situations, i.e. when using Node or when using Ember.  This is a specific situation an expert may be able to advise on - there may be specific considerations when using both these technologies, but the question needs to be open to find that out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In my opinion there is no doubt you will want to use handlebars for your Ember templates. One of the biggest features of ember is data binding and how it works with handlebars. If you 100% want to manage handling updating everything manually when data changes within the application then you can use whatever templating engine you want. But in that case I am not even sure you want to use Ember.

In the typical use case you will only be returning JSON from the nodejs server and you won't need to use a templating engine to handle returning JSON.

What I have done is just created a static html page for the Ember application and the used node as an api server part of the application.  All of the views are rendered through Ember.  The only time a call is made to node is to get data for ember to use to generate the views, or to handle persisting changes to data.

Here is an example of how I tend to handle your stack.  This is just the starting point of a little side project I am playing with to learn Ember that might help.

https://github.com/fredjiles/embgo

Comment: In my opinion there is no doubt you will want to use handlebars for your Ember templates. -- why?  this isn't justified at all.

Comment: Why?  Have you looked at the Ember documentation?  One of the biggest features of ember is data binding and how they work with handlebars.  If you 100% want to manage handling updating everything manually when data changes within the application then you can use whatever templating engine you want.  But in that case I am not even sure you want to use Ember.

Comment: Also if you are looking for more 'Haml' like syntax maybe you could use http://emblemjs.com/ for writing your templates.

Comment: Great.  That information partly answers the OP's question, so add it to your answer.  At present your answer just asserts your opinion.

Comment: More importantly this doesn't answer the question, it just lists reasons handlebars is good, so downvote stands.